# Migration from Jboss 5 to Jboss 6 causes SOAP request error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, cxf

Currently we are migrating from AS5 to AS6 and for now everything works fine exept SOAP request creation.
I know that Jboss 6 is using "jbossws-cxf..." libs.
The problem is that now I'm  getting strange beghavior of SOAP request:

```
ID: 6
Address: Some Address
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {SOAPAction=["http://....."], Accept=[*/*]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><GetInfo xmlns="http://.....">
<ID>SomeId</ID><Username>SomeUN</Username><Password>SomePWD</Password></GetInfo></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

--------------------------------------
2014-06-11 13:42:29,715 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 6
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], X-AspNet-Version=[2.0.50727], Date=[Wed, 11 Jun 2014 10:43:09 GMT], 
Content-Length=[924], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], Cache-Control=[private]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Invalid SOAP message due to XML Schema validation failure. The element 'GetInfo' in namespace 'http://...' has invalid child element 'ID' in namespace 'http://....'. 
List of possible elements expected: 'Cred, Auth' in namespace 'http://....'.</faultstring><faultactor>http://....</faultactor><detail><exception code="00010222" xmlns="http://...." /></detail>
</soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

---

```
2014-06-11 13:42:29,958 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].        [localhost].[/HelloWorld].[resteasy-servlet]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Servlet.service() 
 for servlet resteasy-servlet threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Invalid SOAP message due to XML Schema validation failure. 
 The element 'GetInfo' in namespace 'http://...' has invalid child element 'ID' in namespace 'http://....'. List of possible elements expected: 'Cred, Auth' in namespace 'http://...'.
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [:]
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [:]
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [:]
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [:]
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [:]
 at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [:6.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [:6.1.0.Final]
```

Basically for some reason Jboss 6 removes 'Cred' wrapper node, on Jboss 5 everything works ok and request is formed correctly.

Here is a sample code:
.....

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"cred",
"auth"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetInfo")
public class GetInfo {

@XmlElement(name = "Cred")
protected Cred cred;
@XmlElement(name = "Auth")
protected String auth;
```

....

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Cred", propOrder = {
"ID",
"username",
"password"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Cred")
public class Cred {
@XmlElement(name = "ID", required = true)
protected String ID;
@XmlElement(name = "Username", required = true)
protected String username;
@XmlElement(name = "Password", required = true)
protected String password;
```

....

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetInfo", action = "http://........")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "GetInfo", targetNamespace = "http://........", className = "com.test.GetInfo")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetnfoResponse", targetNamespace = "http://......", className = "com.test.GetInfoResponse")
public void getInfo(
    @WebParam(name = "Cred", targetNamespace = "http://.....")
    Cred cred,
    @WebParam(name = "Auth", targetNamespace = "http://.....", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT)
    Holder<String> auth,
    @WebParam(name = "AccInfo", targetNamespace = "http://.....", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<AccountInfo> accInfo,
    @WebParam(name = "Address", targetNamespace = "http://.....", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<Address> address,
    @WebParam(name = "Email", targetNamespace = ".....", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<String> email);
```

Could anyone advise me what could be the problem with Jboss 6 cxf migration?

P.S. If you have some problems with migration from Jboss 5 to Jboss 6 you are welcome to ask me

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I have fixed this error by regenerating classes by using cxf tool. Jboss 6 is using cxf libs, but Jboss 5 was working with "axis".